# In iOS 12.0.1 on iPhone, what is the point of the block list? It doesn't block calls

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, caller-id

I get spam calls on my iPhone SE. I have caller ID.

I have a contact called "do not answer". The contact is blocked

Inside the "do not answer" contact I keep a list of all the spam numbers that call me.

In iOS 12.0.1 I get calls saying `Incoming call from "do not answer"`. How is this possible? Doesn't the phone app see its showing the "do not answer" contact that should be blocked?

The only workaround I have found is to set my "do not answer" contact to have a silent ringtone without vibration but it still interrupts use of my phone

This has been ongoing since my iPhone 4s days

Comment: You said "The contact is blocked".  How did you block the contact?  If you block a contact, any phone number assigned to that contact should also be blocked.  You're seeing a 'Incoming call from 'do not answer'" tells me the number they're using is already assigned to a blocked contact.  Is that correct?

Comment: @fsb Tap on the contact, scroll to the bottom, choose "Block this caller". your assumption is correct

Comment: @fsb The block doesn’t include numbers added to the contact after it has been blocked.

Comment: @MikeScott That doesn't sound correct.  The OP received a notification that 'do not answer' called them.  That means iOS identified the number was already assigned to a blocked contact.  It should've blocked that number regardless of when that number was added to the contact.  [Apple's page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201229) on blocking calls/contacts imply the contact will be blocked.

Comment: @fsb Why don’t you just try it for yourself? Blocking a contact doesn’t actually block the contact, it blocks all phone numbers _currently_ assigned to that contact. You can easily verify that what I’m saying is correct.

Comment: @MikeScott link?

Comment: @user1886419 I don’t have a link, I’m reporting the result of _actually trying it out_.

Comment: @MikeScott but is this a bug or a feature? seems very unintuitive. saying you tried it doesn't prove anything. i would need official docs from apple and i will upvote and mark your answer as correct

Comment: This is strange because Apple's description of the feature says "You will not receive phone calls from people on the block list".  It doesn't say, anywhere, that numbers added to the contact later require the contact to be re-blocked. I will try to find a number to test this, as @MikeScott suggested.

Comment: really appreciate the help and attention to detail @fsb

Comment: OMG!  @MikeScott is correct!  I tried this and the call wasn't blocked, exactly as he described.  Nice find!

Comment: @fsb so does this need to be bug reported to apple?

Comment: Personally, **I** think it's a bug.  I don't know if Apple thinks it's a bug (or a feature).  It appears to work differently than how Apple describes it.  I don't know if you can use the Apple bug reporter for this, you might need to use the [Feedback form](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html).

Answer (score 1):

If a contact has more than one phone number, you have to block each number separately. Have you blocked every individual phone number that’s assigned to your “Do not contact” contact?

Comment: where is the option? i just see the one at the bottom of the contact, all indications would say this blocks every number in the contact

Comment: @user1886419 Settings / Phone / Call Blocking and Identification

Comment: I see a long list of "do not answer"

Comment: @user1886419 But does that list include every number that’s assigned to that contact?

Comment: assuming so. would i have to go back to this list each time i add a number to the contact? what is the point of the block this caller option that can be found on each contact in the phone/contacts app?

Comment: @user1886419 Yes, it won’t automatically block new numbers added to a contact that you have previously blocked.

Comment: Upvote for teaching me something I didn't know (even though I thought I did).

Answer (score 1):

Write down each number you want to block and block each one separately. I had a iPhone SE and started to block numbers I did not want as they came in. 
That worked for me.

Comment: i can't afford an apple pencil unfortunately :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is actually not possible with the Phone app on your iPhone.

Like the commenters suggest you can't block a contact by the name that shows up on your iPhone's screen. I understand *why* you did that but the underlying logic of the phone doesn't work that way, for whatever reason.

The "Do Not Call" list is mostly a joke that few companies respect.

I have found some success with the "Call protect" app from AT&T which marks calls as "Telemarketer." "Potential Fraud," and the like, though they still ring. There is a free tier (which I use) and a paid tier that supposedly offers more protection. Of course that only works if you have AT&T. If you don't have AT&T call your carrier and see if they offer something similar.

The only **real** solution to this issue is in the hands of our government, making penalties for phone spamming much more severe might cut down on this. Until then we have to rely on imperfect technological solutions, much like those that filter email spam.

Comment: what does my question have to do with the do not call list? i am not on this. there are callers that constantly call me that I would like to block. they are on my do not answer list

Comment: It's another point of reference. you can only block a number, not a person or a company if they use a different number

Comment: was that not established in my OP?